# android volley failed to load images

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I want the timeline of the app to be like facebook so i followed this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/).

the timeline works fine but volley failed to load the profile pic and the post image .

[image: here is my project structure]

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // url is null, remove from the view
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("null","image");
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

if you need more info about the code to help me please notify me
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

1.you can use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load image from url look the below code it can help you in simple way

compile this  dependency inside gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

than load image like this

```
Glide.with(HomeClass.this)
            .load(url)
            .into(imageview);
```

2 .try this if you dont want to use third party library

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

3 use  [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) for image loading in ImageView.
dependency inside gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

**than load image in image view like this**

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(img_url).noFade().into(imageview);
```

i hope that it will work in your case

Comment: here is my logcat   07-25 14:30:29.536 24756-24812/com.example.fcb.test1 E/Volley: [22842] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 for http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery_mos.jpg

Comment: @AbdelazizWaheedLasheen can your post your code of glide

Comment: inside my FeedListAdapter class  // user profile pic
        Glide.with(profilePic.getContext()).load(item.getProfilePic()).into(profilePic);

Comment: i think put context not context of profile like MainActivity.this

Comment: Tried using  picasso it gives me the same result, and the same logcat

Comment: but your need to pass context my friend pass context like this Activity.this

Comment: if it now work than use custom class that i mention in my ans it will sure help you

Comment: user profile pic Glide.with(activity).load(item.getProfilePic(‌​)).into(profi‌​lePic);

Comment: should  i use findviewbyid on main activity for the networkimageview

Comment: no just use simple imageview my friend not networkimageview

Comment: thank you very much the problem was solved when i used imageview instead of networkImageview

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso for image loading in ImageView.

```
ImageView imageview_obj;
Picasso.with(activity).load(img_url).noFade().into(imageview_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Picasso for image loading in ImageView. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

It is very simple and powerful library for image downloading and caching. [Simple tutorial for Picasso library](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/)

Answer (score 0):

Are u add gradle file inside dependencies

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

And load to use this line

```
 Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .into(yourImageview);
```

Comment: Yes new version is available.Use this gradle plugin                          
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'

Comment: inside my FeedListAdapter class // user profile pic Glide.with(profilePic.getContext()).load(item.getProfilePic(‌​)).into(profilePic);                                                                                       change from this line below as should worked. u should pass activity then worked fine... 
inside my FeedListAdapter class // user profile pic Glide.with(activity).load(item.getProfilePic(‌​)).into(profilePic);

Comment: @Abdelaziz Waheed Lasheen Are u try this one